# Where does the android emulator data lies?

Tags: android

Where does the emulator data lie(the contacts, messages, saved images)?

Answer (score 8):

Go to ddms,you can find the file explorer from that you will get application directry and sd card filed you can find all the detailed files there.

Answer (score 1):

In ~/.android  (that is your user directory/.android)

Answer (score 0):

Each application stores its own data in its own private folder in /data/data on the emulator. Depending on the application it potentially can also store data on the /sdcard (e.g. downloaded images or whatever) which by convention should then be in /sdcard/Android/data/com.yourappspackage.and.so/ so that it gets cleaned up with uninstall but many apps also throw stuff all over the sd card (although they should not..)

More is on the dev site e.g. at http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

All this is the same for the emulator as well as the real device. The emulator is just a virtual machine running on qemu.

Answer (score 0):

You can use File Explorer tool in eclipse or ddms to View The data in the emulator

else use terminal to view the data using the command,

adb shell

Thank you,
Ganapathy.